# Error installing the RetroArch Emulator on my iPhone 4S?

Tags: ios, emulation

I go to the CoolROM website and navigate to the non-jailbroken iOS download and I tap it. It appears in my home screen and says "Waiting.." I wait until it gets about 3/4 of the way through and it says "Installing.."

I know I have to change the time to 2012, so I then change the date in my phone back to some time in 2012. After a while an error message pops up and says:

> Could not be downloaded at this time"

and it gives me the option to retry. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Could you add more info?

Comment: Well, I go to the CoolROM website and navigate to the non-jail broken iOS download and I tap it. Then it appears in my home screen and says "Waiting.." I wait until it gets about 3/4 of the way through and says "Installing.." Then I change the date in my phone back to some time in 2012. After a while an error message pops up and says "Could not be downloaded at this time" and it gives me the option to retry.

Comment: Well darn. Do you know of any other Playstation One Emulators for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that their developer license has expired, so the apps will not install no matter what.